# Can't profile CoreData with iOS 5

Tags: xcode, core-data

My app (in fact, any app, even the sample ones) keep crashing when trying to Profile them with the Core Data template and iOS5.

They work fine with just the simulator (no core data profiling) or on the device.

They also work fine, and I can use core data instruments, if I compile for iOS 4.3

Comment: As a matter of fact, if I create a new single view application, and without typing anything I go a profile it with Core Data instruments, it crashes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just reinstalled XCode and it seems to work now. Weird.